# XSLT. If variable is true copy node and update attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml similar to this:

```
<a>
   <b attr1="1" attr2="2" attr3="3"></b>
</a>
```

Let say I need to change value of attr2 to 22 if attr1 exists or not empty and store the resulting xml to variable.

For now I have something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="bla">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="b/@attr1 or b/@attr1 != ''">
            true
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            false
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="blabla">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$bla">
            <xsl:call-template name="ggg">
                <xsl:with-param name="ccc" select="b"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="b"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template name="ggg">
    <xsl:param name="ccc"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
    <xsl:attribute name="attr2">22</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
</xsl:template>
```

But it's not working and I think i'm going into wrong direction.

Please help.

---- UPDATE ----
Desired output:

```
<a>
    <b attr1="1" attr2="22" attr3="3"></b>
</a>
```

and it should be stored into variable, because I need to pass it again.

Comment: Can you specify what is the desired output? Storing value in a variable may not be the best solution for your case.

Comment: when will u use the variable later and what for? You can for example pass variable by applying templates with parameters, bit you should still be more precise on the use case (storing variable is probably only one way of getting what you want).

Comment: this xml can be a part of big xml and in some cases I need to use this one with the changes or another one, depend on variable value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this (XSLT 1.0) :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="b/@attr2">
        <xsl:attribute name="attr2">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="../@attr1">22</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or XSLT 2.0 (more concise):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="b/@attr2">
        <xsl:attribute name="attr2" 
                      select="if (exists(../@attr1)) then 22 else ."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You although may use global variable to store it for a later use. In this case you just have to add something like :

```
<xsl:variable name="blabla" select="/a/b/@attr1"/>
```

as a child of `xsl:stylesheet` given that the `/a/b/@attr1` node is unique. In your example, the problem is that selecting `b/@attr1` wont select anything because the default context is the root (`/`) in global variables.

Comment: As I said I need to store the resulting xml into variable.

Comment: No, it won't work. I need a resulting xml to be stored for later use not attribute value.

Comment: you can do that using XSLT 2.0. The result of the ``select`` will be an attribute node in the case above. With XSLT 1.0 you have to use specific extension (e.g. exslt).

Comment: b/@attr1 does not select anything (last paragraph of my answer). Prefer using ``/a/b/@attr1``. Be aware that it will select all @attr1 that matches the XPath expression.